# How can we render a plot inline which is drawn using scatter3d() function in 'car' package

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a graph in R jupyter notebook. I'm looking for a command similar to "%matplotlib inline"  in python.

When i execute the scatter3d() command it generates a plot in a separate window but i want the plot to be displayed inline.

Comment: Does this work?

options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')

Comment: Regular plots show up inline by default, but I guess that the 3d plot is doing something different. What package are you using to generate that?

Comment: options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png') did not work. I am using "car" and "rgl" packages to generate the plot.